# Testing custom Gradle plugin with Test Kit

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to test a custom Gradle plugin using [Test Kit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html).

When executing the test, Gradle isn't able to find the plugin under test

```
group 'com.example'
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        simplePlugin {
            id = 'example'
            implementationClass = 'com.example.ExamplePlugin'
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    writeFile(settingsFile, "rootProject.name = 'hello-world'");
    writeFile(buildFile, "plugins { id 'com.example.example' }");

    BuildResult result = GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(testProjectDir.getRoot())
            .withArguments("exampleTask")
            .build();

    assertThat(result.getOutput()).contains("Hello World!");

    assertThat(result.task(":exampleTask"))
            .isNotNull()
            .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("outcome", TaskOutcome.SUCCESS);
}
```

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.example.example'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

I have put together a repo with the [minimal failing example](https://github.com/ptomli/example-gradle-plugin), using Gradle 6.5. The Test Kit documentation tells me that the "Java Gradle Plugin development plugin" will provide direct integration with Test Kit, but the error I'm getting is suggesting the plugin under test isn't available on the classpath.

I've tried to find another, working, example plugin being tested with Test Kit, but nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were a couple of issues in my code

1. I was missing `.withPluginClasspath()` on the `GradleRunner`
2. The TestKit doesn't need group prefix, `plugins { id 'example' }`